# как растянуть канвас-бекграунд на всю страницу?

Tags: html, css

Поиск постоянно выкидывает на "как растянуть на всю высоту окна". Мне же нужно, чтоб растягивалось на высоту страницы. Сейчас же страница имеет фон лишь в начале, а при скролле все убегает..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

 <style>
  .back{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: yellow;
   top:0px;
      padding: 10px;
  }
  .canv{
   height:100%;
   width:95%;   
   background-color: green;   
  }
  
  .section{
   height:300px;
   border: 5px solid red;
   margin: 10px;
  }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="back"><canvas class="canv"></canvas></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>
<div class="section"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В общем, не нашел ничего лучше, чем JSом подгонять размеры по событию "resize". Костыль(

Answer (score 3):

Задавая блоку с классом `.back` свойство `position: fixed;` и высоту `100%` то его высота будет всегда ровной видимой части страницы. Я поменял высоту `convas` в `90%`-ов что бы наглядно видно было это (эту высоту вы потом сделайте опять равной `100%` если вам так будет нужно). И у вас `convas` всегда будет в видимой части страницы, и его размеры то же будут пропорциональны размерам видимой части страницы.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

<style>
    .back{
        height:100%; 
        width:100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: yellow;
        top:0px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .canv{
        height:90%;
        width:95%;   
        background-color: green;   
    }

    .section{
        height:300px;
        border: 5px solid red;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="back">
        <canvas class="canv"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вместо "Вам так нужно да?" лучше писать что-то вроде "Вам нужно выставить канвасу [position: fixed](https://learn.javascript.ru/position#position-fixed)"

Comment: @Darth Так то же можно

Comment: нет, мне нужна прокрутка фона вместе со страницей. Прибить гвоздями я умею)

Comment: @user3444737 А фон должен быть во всей видимой части страницы? или меньше?

Comment: @user3444737 Для `.back` если я вас правильно понял надо поставить определенную высоту.

Comment: желательно во всей. Фон у меня динамический и в зависимости от положения других элементов. Типа, точки бегают вдоль путей, вокруг элементов. Да, высоту надо поставить для  `.back`. Но если поставить 100%, то почему-то за полную высоту берется высота экрана, а не высота реального предка-контейнера.